# How to get JSON Data of Contacts using XERO API?

Tags: xero-api

I tried by below url
https://api.xero.com/api.xro/2.0/Contacts
but got error as
oauth_problem=consumer_key_unknown&oauth_problem_advice=Consumer%20key%20was%20not%20recognised

how to solve this error ?
what is the Pattern of URL for get method using Consumer key and consumer secret key?

Answer (score 1):

This is because of authorization you are not authorized.

Now Xero deprecated Oauth1 and using Oauth2 you need the following:
client_id
client_secret
redirectUri  //call back URL which Xero hit

For getting this you need to fill the following :

Go to the URL https://developer.xero.com/myapps/ (To create new app).

App name (name of the app eg xyz).

Company or application URL (your application's live URL eg: https:www.google.com)

OAuth 2.0 redirect URIs (call back URL which Xero hit on an authorization eg: http://localhost:10010/api/callback)

Then generate secret and save

Code example for node : https://github.com/XeroAPI/node-oauth2-example/blob/master/index.js

In place of authorizationCallback use oauthCallback function.

Comment: This is because of authorization you are not authorized.
https://developer.xero.com/documentation/auth-and-limits/oauth-issues

Answer (score 0):

Best place to start would be https://developer.xero.com/

There you will find documentation about how to OAuth an app, and links to SDKs with examples on making calls.

You can get your key and secret by signing up to https://developer.xero.com/myapps

Comment: Tank you philals.. I have the keys but how i can get REST Api of contacts through URL.

Comment: Hi. Make sure to check out the documentation. The documentation specific to Contacts is here: https://developer.xero.com/documentation/api/contacts

Answer (score 0):

Access to Xero API endpoints is controlled with oAuth 1.0a - therefore each request requires several parameters be passed and the payload have a correct oauth signature.

If you just want to get the data without coding, I recommend trying the API previewer - login at https://app.xero.com/ set the "Accept Type" to json.

Another option is Postman ...
https://developer.xero.com/documentation/tools/postman

If you are using code - I recommend using one of SDKs as they handle all the gnarly bits of oauth signatures, etc.

For PHP users we just create a Sample App that shows off most endpoints.
https://github.com/XeroAPI/xero-php-sample-app